# Transposing rows into columns and concatenate rows of strings into one string with a specified separator

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to transpose rows into columns and concatenate rows of strings into one string with a specified separator.

**My table:**

| type | name | num | age | dateA | DateB | PRICE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Aziz | 1 | 12 | 2012-01-11 00:00:00.000 | 2012-01-11 00:00:00.000 | 129.00 |
| B | Aziz | 1 | 34 | 2012-01-11 00:00:00.000 | 2012-01-11 00:00:00.000 | 100.00 |
| C | Aziz | 0 | 20 | 2012-01-11 00:00:00.000 | 2012-01-11 00:00:00.000 | 349.00 |
| D | Aziz | 1 | 90 | 2012-01-11 00:00:00.000 | 2012-01-11 00:00:00.000 | 222.00 |

**The result I'd like to have:**

| name | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Aziz | 1, 12,2012-01-11,2012-01-11,129.00 | 1, 34, 2012-01-11, 2012-01-11, 100.00 | 0,20,2012-01-11, 2012-01-11, 349.00 | 1,90,2012-01-11, 2012-01-11,222.00 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT - Removed the CROSS APPLY.   I was going to use a conditional aggregation and decided to go straight PIVOT.

```
Select *
 From  (
        Select Name 
              ,Type
              ,Str = concat(num,',',age,',',convert(date,dateA),',',convert(date,dateB),',',Price)
         From YourTable A
       ) src
 Pivot ( max(Str) for Type in ([A],[B],[C],[D] ) ) pvt
```

**Results**

[image]

Comment: but CROSS APPY its just for agregate in my case i need to transpose rows  into columns also

Comment: @Azizbouchtaoui The CROSS APPLY creates the string per record.   The PIVOT transposes the rows into columns.   What am I missing ?

Comment: SORRY, i was wrong, its OK working fine, thnak you Mr you save my life <3

Comment: Hi John; please can you take a look to this question : https://stackoverflow.com/q/74302268/19123196

Comment: @Azizbouchtaoui apologies for the late response (currently on the west coast).  here is a a dynamic version  https://dbfiddle.uk/AtsMGngH ... Rhythm's solution is good, but this is a more  data driven