# Transposing multiple rows to single row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to transpose rows into columns and concatenate type with header to get one line.

**My table:**

| type | name | num | age | dateA | DateB | PRICE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Aziz | 1 | 12 | 2012-01-11 00:00:00.000 | 2012-01-11 00:00:00.000 | 129.00 |
| B | Aziz | 1 | 34 | 2012-01-11 00:00:00.000 | 2012-01-11 00:00:00.000 | 100.00 |
| C | Aziz | 0 | 20 | 2012-01-11 00:00:00.000 | 2012-01-11 00:00:00.000 | 349.00 |
| D | Aziz | 1 | 90 | 2012-01-11 00:00:00.000 | 2012-01-11 00:00:00.000 | 222.00 |

**The result I'd like to have:**

| name | num x A | age x A | dateA x A | DateB x A | PRICE x A | num x B | age x B | dateA x B | DateB x B | PRICE x B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Aziz | 1 | 12 | 2012-01-11 | 2012-01-11 | 129.00 | 1 | 34 | 2012-01-11 | 2012-01-11 | 100.00 |

the same thing with C and D all in one line

Comment: What did you try? Did you read this? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: That's not what transposition means, in any application. In Excel, all spreadsheets, Pandas etc it means turning rows to columns. Why do you want this result? It's far easier to calculate this on the client. There's no way to produce this without very complex and expensive dynamic SQL. A query can't have an unknown number of columns so you have to count all rows and add the column names in a dynamic SQL string, then execute the new string to produce that result. Essentially, you'll execute the query twice

Comment: in my case i have jst A,B,C,D type so i think its possible to do this

Comment: on what basis you want row to appear, the same name can occur again also. you want name x A, name x B also ?

Comment: no name is the distinct and after that num x A , age x A, .... num x B, age x B ... OR  num x A , num x B, age x A , age x B..

Comment: Use conditional aggregation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this the long way like this:

```
SELECT name, 
  [num x A]   = MAX(CASE type WHEN 'A' THEN num END),
  [age x A]   = MAX(CASE type WHEN 'A' THEN age END),
  [dateA x A] = MAX(CASE type WHEN 'A' THEN dateA END),
  [DateB x A] = MAX(CASE type WHEN 'A' THEN DateB END),
  [PRICE x A] = MAX(CASE type WHEN 'A' THEN PRICE END),
  [num x B]   = MAX(CASE type WHEN 'B' THEN num END),
  [age x B]   = MAX(CASE type WHEN 'B' THEN age END),
  [dateA x B] = MAX(CASE type WHEN 'B' THEN dateA END),
  [DateB x B] = MAX(CASE type WHEN 'B' THEN DateB END),
  [PRICE x B] = MAX(CASE type WHEN 'B' THEN PRICE END),
  [num x C]   = MAX(CASE type WHEN 'C' THEN num END),
  [age x C]   = MAX(CASE type WHEN 'C' THEN age END),
  [dateA x C] = MAX(CASE type WHEN 'C' THEN dateA END),
  [DateB x C] = MAX(CASE type WHEN 'C' THEN DateB END),
  [PRICE x C] = MAX(CASE type WHEN 'C' THEN PRICE END),
  [num x D]   = MAX(CASE type WHEN 'D' THEN num END),
  [age x D]   = MAX(CASE type WHEN 'D' THEN age END),
  [dateA x D] = MAX(CASE type WHEN 'D' THEN dateA END),
  [DateB x D] = MAX(CASE type WHEN 'D' THEN DateB END),
  [PRICE x D] = MAX(CASE type WHEN 'D' THEN PRICE END)
FROM dbo.YourTableName GROUP BY name;
```

Working example [in this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/z50u9kv5).

You can also do this dynamically, which will help if there are more types added later, or the schema changes:

```
DECLARE @sql   nvarchar(max), 
        @types varchar(32)   = 'A,B,C,D',
        @cols  nvarchar(max) = N'num,age,dateA,DateB,PRICE';

SELECT @sql = STRING_AGG(o, ',' + char(13) + char(10)) FROM
(
  SELECT QUOTENAME(CONCAT(c.value, ' x ', t.value))
    + CONCAT(' = MAX(CASE type WHEN ', 
      QUOTENAME(t.value, char(39)), N' THEN ', c.value, N' END)')
    FROM STRING_SPLIT(@types, ',') AS t
  CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(@cols, ',') AS c
) AS x(o);

SET @sql = N'SELECT name, 
' + @sql + N' FROM dbo.YourTableName GROUP BY name;';

EXECUTE sys.sp_executesql @sql;
```

That is demonstrated [in this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Pij3jTHu).